# Gerund passive with the verb "want"

Tags: verbs, gerunds

Is it correct to say:

- The kid wants washing.
- The kid wants playing.

How to know what gerunds can be used with the verbs "want", "need", and "require"?

Comment: "The kid wants washing." sounds strange to my ears. Have you encountered that sentence in English text? In other words, how do you determine it is "correct"?

Comment: @RuslanD Okay, you made me thinking, probably what I remember is not that correct in fact. I changed the question to a more specific point.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/want) from the Cambridge dictionary provides some details of the different uses of "want".

In short, "want" can have different meanings - you can use it to say that something needs to happen ("The kitchen **wants** painting."), or you can use it in its primary sense of "having a wish or desire ("The boy **wants** to play with his friends."). When you use it to talk about things that need to happen, the structure is "want + -ing", otherwise it's "want + to".

"Need" can similarly be used to talk about what should happen - e.g. "the car **needs** washing" - so it's an alternative to "want", and I'd say the more common alternative in American English. It can also be used to talk about what a person needs - e.g. "I **need** to talk to you."

Given that context, your first sentence really means that the kid is probably a bit dirty and should take a shower. I'd rephrase it as "The kid **needs a bath**/**needs a shower**", which is a more idiomatic way of saying the same thing. You don't typically talk about "washing" a person - you wash things like a car, a kitchen, the dishes, etc.

Your second sentence is strange, because just as "wants washing" means "needs to be washed", "wants playing" means "needs to be played". How do you "play" a kid? I think what you're trying to say is that what the kid wants is to play, so you'd just say "The kid **wants to play**."

Comment: upvoted. "The kid wants washing" sounds like old English, but I have not actually heard it used.  It sounds like it would mean the same as "the kid is in need of a good washing" or "the kid is in want of a good washing" both of which I have read (the last example is not common orally, at least today or in my [Canadian English] circles)

Comment: @michael I just found this excerpt from "A Warm Southern Wind" via Google Books: "I need a basin of water, a washcloth and a towel. The captain is in need of a good washing." Thanks for pointing that expression out for me :)

Comment: I've heard your options before, but the one I am asking is indeed "wants washing". True that it is preferably used with inanimates rather than the living. However, that's exactly what I remember. It's just that I checked the grammar and couldn't find the same for the verb "play" and many others.

Comment: @SovereignSun "wants washing" is fine, just not what most people would say. "wants playing" doesn't work for the reasons I explained in my answer. Was my answer helpful to you, or should I clarify the difference a little more? To summarize - the question isn't what verb comes after "want" - it's about which meaning of "want" you're using.

Comment: @RuslanD If we think that way then "The chicken wants eating" means "The chicken should be fed" which is also correct?

Comment: @SovereignSun the structure "X wants Y-ing" means "X needs to be Y'ed" or, equivalently, "someone needs to Y the X". So for example, "the kitchen wants cleaning" means "the kitchen needs to be cleaned"/"someone needs to clean the kitchen". So "the chicken wants eating" = "someone needs to eat the chicken". If you want to say that someone needs to **feed** the chicken, rather than **eat** the chicken, you'd say "the chicken wants **feeding**". Does that help?

Comment: @RuslanD Yup, it does!